# Approximating hypergeometric function F(1,1+a,2+a,z) for z->1

Tags: special-functions, approximation, hypergeometric-function

in my studies a normalization constant for a pmf includes the hypergeometric function
${}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z)$

The parameters are in the range $0.99<z<1$ and $0<a<5$.

I have tried some approximations for presentations including incomplete Beta and Lerch-Phi functions but z being near 1 does not give reasonable results.

Inserting the parameters yield for example

${}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z)=(1+a) \Phi(z,1,1+a)=(1+a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1+a+n}$

$=(1+a) \int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(-(1+a)t)}{1-z \exp(-t)} dt$

$=(1+a) \int_0^1 \frac{t^a}{1-tz} dt$

Plotting the integrand from the last line, it looks like some power function could be a good fit, but maybe there are other alternatives, for example a transformation with $1-z$.

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last integral formula for the hypergeometric function is off; according to Wikipedia it should be

$$
{}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z) = (1+a) \int_0^1 \frac{t^a}{1-tz}\,dt.
$$

Now if we make the change of variables $tz = s$ we get

$$
{}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z) = \frac{1+a}{z^{1+a}} \int_0^z \frac{s^a}{1-s}\,ds. \tag{1}
$$

Heuristically, the integrand is largest when $s \approx z \approx 1$, and there we have

$$
\frac{s^a}{1-s} \approx \frac{1}{1-s},
$$

so we might expect that

$$
\int_0^z \frac{s^a}{1-s}\,ds \approx \int_0^z \frac{1}{1-s}\,ds = -\log(1-z).
$$

To quantify this we'll essentially pull out the largest part of the integrand.  To wit, we write

$$
\frac{s^a}{1-s} = \frac{s^a - 1 + 1}{1-s} = \frac{1}{1-s} + \frac{s^a-1}{1-s},
$$

and split the integral up like

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^z \frac{s^a}{1-s}\,ds &= \int_0^z \frac{1}{1-s}\,ds + \int_0^z \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds \\
&= -\log(1-z) + \int_0^z \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds. \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

The remaining integral actually converges as $z \to 1^-$.  In fact we have

$$
\lim_{z \to 1^-} \int_0^z \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds = \int_0^1 \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds = -H_a,
$$

where $H_a$ is a [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments).  So, we can actually rewrite $(2)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^z \frac{s^a}{1-s}\,ds &= -\log(1-z) + \int_0^1 \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds - \int_z^1 \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds \\
&= -\log(1-z) - H_a - \int_z^1 \frac{s^a-1}{1-s}\,ds, \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

and now the last integral here tends to zero as $z \to 1^-$.  Combining this with $(1)$ we see that, in this sense,

> $$
> {}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z) \approx -\frac{1+a}{z^{1+a}} \Bigl(\log(1-z) + H_a\Bigr)
> $$
>   as $z \to 1^-$.

If more accuracy is required we could further study the remaining integral in $(3)$.  The integrand is analytic near $s = 1$, so we can expand it in power series and integrate term-by-term.  Indeed, by the binomial theorem we have

$$
s^a = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} (s-1)^n,
$$

so

$$
\frac{s^a-1}{1-s} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{a}{n} (s-1)^{n-1},
$$

thus

$$
\begin{align}
\int_z^1 \frac{s^a-1}{1-s} \,ds &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} \int_z^1 (s-1)^{n-1}\,ds \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} \frac{(z-1)^n}{n}.
\end{align}
$$

So, combining this with $(3)$ and $(1)$,

> $$
> {}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z) = -\frac{1+a}{z^{1+a}} \left(\log(1-z) + H_a + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} \frac{(z-1)^n}{n}\right).
> $$

The series inside may be truncated after as many terms as are needed to obtain the desired accuracy.

Comment: Numerically, using the first two terms of the power series displayed in the last formula yields a maximum error of about $2.12 \times 10^{-5}$ for all $0.99 < z < 1$ and $0 < a < 5$.  It seems that the largest error occurs when $a$ is close to $5$.  The maximum error when $a$ is restricted to $0<a<2$ is about $5.72 \times 10^{-8}$, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and unterstandable explanation. I don't know if using the Harmonic number (which is an integral itself and Mathematica shows nearly no speed advantage) is very useful but the techniques you used helped me alot :)

Comment: You're very welcome.  I suppose to get over the $H_a$ hurdle you could precompute some rational approximation to it, for example $$r(a) = \frac{1.60190+0.83926(a-2.5)+0.08003(a-2.5)^2}{0.95330+0.31218(a-2.5)+0.01692(a-2.5)^2},$$ which was computed using the Mathematica command `EconomizedRationalApproximation[HarmonicNumber[a],{a,{0,5},2,2}]//N` (make sure to include the FunctionApproximations package first).  Using this, the approximation $${}_2F_1(1,1+a,2+a,z) \approx -\frac{1+a}{z^{1+a}}\left(\log(1-z) + r(a) + a(z-1)\right)$$ seems to be accurate to within about $0.015$.